# Calculating Exponents in AT&T Assembly

Tags: math, assembly, att, pow

How would I go about doing exponents in AT&T assembly, such as x ^ y with x = 3, and y = 10?

Say that r14 has value 3. r15 has value 10. Where r14 = x, and r15 = y.

Could I do this to calculate the exponent of x ^ y? If not how do I calculate exponents in AT&T assembly?

.globl functionWithItems

```
functionWithItems:
     //Do some stuff that I want here.
     //I need to x ^ y
     jmp .power
.power:
    imulq %r14, %r14
    dec %r15        
    cmpq $-1, %r15
    jne .power
    jmp .continueOtherPartsOfProgram

.continueOtherPartsOfProgram:
    //Do some stuff after doing the power. r14 should now contain x ^ y.
    ret
```

After revising the code:

```
.globl functionWithItems

functionWithItems:
     //Do some stuff that I want here.
     //I need to x ^ y
     cmpq $0, %r15
     je .zeroValue
     movq %r14, %rbx 
     cmpq $2, %r15
     jge .numberTimes
     jmp .continueOtherPartsOfProgram

.zeroValue:
     movq $1, %rbx
     jmp .continueOtherPartsOfProgram

.numberTimes:
     dec %r15 
     jmp .power

.power:
    imulq %r14, %rbx
    dec %r15        
    cmpq $0, %r15
    jne .power
    jmp .continueOtherPartsOfProgram

.continueOtherPartsOfProgram:
    //Do some stuff after doing the power. r14 should now contain x ^ y.
    ret
```

Comment: If the result of the `imulq` is going into r14, then you're calculating x^2, x^4, x^8, etc.

Comment: I changed the code to account for that now user3386109

Comment: Ok, so all that's left is to make sure that the `imulq` executes the correct number of times. If `y` is 1, then `imulq` should execute 0 times (the answer is already in `rbx`). If `y` is 2, then `imulq` should execute 1 time, etc.

Comment: I changed the code now to account for that.

Comment: Seems like that should work. If it does, then I would revert the question to version 1, and post the current code as the answer.